# I cannot use the same code with different files in Nuxt Composables

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am doing request operations using Nuxt composables. My first **composables/states.ts** file I created is working fine:

```
import axios from "axios"

const recent_posts = ref(null)

const get_recent = async() => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/recent')
    .then((response) => {
        recent_posts.value = response.data.posts
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.message)
    })
}

await get_recent()

export const usePosts = () => useState('recent', () => recent_posts)
```

---

But my last created **composables/query.ts** file gives an error even though I did the same process as in states.ts.

**composables/query.ts**:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const visiter = ref(null)

const get_visiter = async() => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/query', {
        refresh: useCookie('REFToken').value
    })
    .then((response) => {
        visiter.value = response.data.user.username
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err.message)
    })
}

await get_visiter()

export const useQuery = async() => useState('query', () => visiter)
```

Here is the error I got in **query.ts**:

```
[nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at `https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#using-vue-and-nuxt-composables`.
```

---

I checked the link https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#using-vue-and-nuxt-composables. When I did the given method, I could not return the result I wanted (Object Promise returned). I will not throw my codes in this method so that the question does not prolong. I just wonder why the same code works in 1 file but not in the other file.

Comment: It depends on where it was actually used, but generally doing a side effect on import is a mistake and doesn't play well with SSR. This, `await get_visiter()`